# Is it mandatory to get an Acces token to use C# facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I found the [C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) and I see only examples that needs the access token acquired through the OAuth process. I only want to access publics albums and pictures is it necessary to register an app and all the OAuth suff ? This seems overkill to access public data.

Comment: I think yes otherwise system can be abused by automated systems.

Comment: Well I found my answer. Using graph api I can access all public stuff. Like this : https://graph.facebook.com/111241738945897/albums. It gives a nice Json response and you can view all the images and albums that are public.